# Efficient way to merge alternating values from two columns into one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns in a table. I want to merge them into a single column, but the merge should be done taking alternate characters from each columns.

For example:

- Column A --> value (1,2,3)
- Column B --> value (A,B,C)

Required result - (1,A,2,B,3,C)

It should be done without loops.

Comment: You'll need to use a split function, then row_number, then concat() them back together.  Best bet is to not store concatenated data in a single column.  Normalize your data, one row for "1", another for "2", another for "3", and "A", etc.. you can then query these child rows and not do string manipulation tricks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `UNION` and get a little creative with how you choose to alternate.  My solution ended up looking like this.

```
SELECT ColumnA
FROM Table
WHERE ColumnA%2=1
UNION
SELECT ColumnB
FROM TABLE
WHERE ColumnA%2=0
```

If you have an ID/PK column that could just as easily be used, I just didn't want to assume anything about your table.

EDIT:
If your table contains duplicates that you wish to keep, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

Try This;

```
 SELECT [value]
    FROM [Table]
    UNPIVOT
    (
        [value] FOR [Column] IN ([Column_A], [Column_B])
    ) UNPVT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL 2016 or higher you can use:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(STRING_AGG (cast(a as varchar(1)) + ',' + b, ','), '()') 
FROM test;
```

In older versions, depending on how much data you have in your tables you can also try:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + cast(a as varchar(1)) + ',' + b
FROM test
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,''), '()')
```

Here you can try a sample

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6c9af/5

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL uses *undocumented* aggregate concatenation technique. This is described in [Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008 T-SQL Programming](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/inside-microsoft-sql-server-2008-t-sql-programming-9780735626027) on page 33.

```
declare @x varchar(max) = '';
declare @t table (a varchar(10), b varchar(10));
insert into @t values (1,'A'), (2,'B'),(3,'C');

select @x = @x + a + ',' + b + ','
from @t;

select '(' + LEFT(@x, LEN(@x) - 1) + ')';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Added explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over order by colA) as rn
    from t
)
select rn,
    case rn % 2 when 1 then colA else colB end as alternating
from data;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.